# Actions on gallery view android

Tags: android, xml, gallery

[image: in the below diagram if i any one of the gallery then i should be able to scroll the below one automatically]i have two gallery views in my single UI screen or you may say activity, i want to have listener in such a way that on scroll of one gallery view the other should also scroll , i tried giving listener to one gallery and calling the other one gallery view into that ., but its working for me , pls can any one help me..

thanks in advance
Datta

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Gallery view is missing a lot of functionality (or is broken) as compared to ListView or GridView. In this particular instance, you need a "setOnCenteredItemChangedListener" or something like that. However, the documentation does not show anything close to this.

One option would be to implement your own Gallery class using HorizontalScrollView.

Another (hacky) option would be to rely on your Gallery adapter to push the current position being fetched (which may **NOT** be the one displayed in the middle) and use that to guess the currently selected position.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the position of one of the galleries with [Gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) and then update the other gallery with [Gallery.setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Unfortunately, "selected" is only triggered when you actually select an item in the Gallery, and not if you scroll around.

Comment: @sparkymat, aw sorry, yes I see the question was not about the selected image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the scroll event of your first gallery and inside this method you should call the `onScroll` event of your second gallery like this,

```
gallery_two.onScroll(MotionEvent e1,MotionEvent e2,x,y);
```

Comment: thank you replying, i am trying with your solution but i am not getting how exactly to follow the instruction , can  you brief it some more extent please.